# The PHP Language Server server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have this error in my vscode after I upgraded to PHP8.

[image]

I tried to increase my memory_limit to `4GB` or `8GB` as [this link](https://github.com/felixfbecker/php-language-server/issues/572) described.

[image]

also, I using the `v2.3.14` (last version) of the `PHP IntelliSense` extension.

[image]

Comment: Kindly check the log and output that `Help / Toggle Developer Tools, tab Console`

Comment: Disable it and contact the author. Also make sure that installed version of plugin supports your PHP version and update it if required.

Comment: Check your [**PHP Error logs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel) and resolve issues that they present.

Comment: If you are using PHP 8 then PHP IntelliSense may not be ready for PHP 8 as version 2.3.14 was only made in late 2019.

Comment: @Martin You are probably right about 2019 made but I'm checking the errors as you mentioned for getting closer to solve the problem. thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since my initial answer is from 2021 and in the meanwhile the extension is not maintained anymore, I recommend to follow the answer of air-dex below.

---

This fixed it for me on PHP 8.0.3:

```
cd ~/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-intellisense-2.3.14/

composer update
```

https://github.com/felixfbecker/php-language-server/issues/779

Comment: I try to run this command on 8.0.7 Win 10, but it seems to be going in some sort of infinite loop of deprecation error message, Is that normal? as I waited for 5 minute but it keep going. and then I quit the command.

Comment: @SumitGupta same with me, have you fixed it?

Comment: @SumitGupta Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/a/332872/1334887) can help you, since Windows may not recognize the  "~" (tilde)

Comment: Well After I break my loop (Ctrl + C) I just restart Code and it works fine without issue. so I never rerun command or do anything after that and it works.

Comment: Got the same deprecation  loop

Comment: Same depreciation loop. My solution was to uninstall this extension.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like Felix Becker's Extension is now unmaintained. I fixed the issue by replacing his extension with Damjan Cvetko's PHP IntelliSense, which is a maintained fork of this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zobo.php-intellisense

Answer (score 5):

I also had same issue on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS trying to use PHP 8.0.2, although my vscode server path is slightly different. Ran the update, reopened vscode and everything is working like it should.

```
cd ~/.vscode-server/extensions/felixfbecker.php-intellisense-2.3.14/
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me is that I had both extensions installed. Uninstalling felix's solved the issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34364961)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is:

`uninstall`

`reload`

`install`